# $.getJSON from MVC WebApi returning deserialized object?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm playing around with the new mvc web api and knockout.js and came across a scenario where $.getJSON is returning a deserialized object vs a json string.  Not really a problem but I'm just curious as to why it's occurring.  Can anyone explain?  Thanks

```
 //Web Api call

 public UserViewModel GetNewUser()
 {
        var userViewModel = new UserViewModel()
        {
             Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
             Name = "Test"
        };

        return userViewModel;
}

//client code
$.getJSON('/api/User/GetNewUser', function (result) {
    //var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
    //result is already parsed to ojbect
}



enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the *documented* "magic" behind [`jQuery.getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> **The success callback is passed the returned data**, which is typically a JavaScript object or array as defined by the JSON structure and **[which is] parsed using the $.parseJSON() method.** It is also passed the text status of the response.

(Where does "knockout.js" fit in this?)